# My hair particles move when in particle edit mode

Tags: particles, vertices, hair, particle-nodes, particle-edit-mode

I'm new to particles and may have missed something but but i'm sure its some bug:
When I switch to particle edit from object mode, the hair particles project towards my screen (pictures below). Also im using vertex groups here but its the same problem if I cover the whole surface
[image: Object mode]

As soon as I click particle edit, this is what I see. Note that the hair now leaves towards the right side of the viewport. Even if I rotate my view, they remain in the same place:
[image: particle edit]

[image]

Comment: please provide your blend file

Comment: Updated with file

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your file.

Comment: Thanks for having a look. I think its my system, windows 7 with no graphics card